# Confusion about tensorflow's max_pooling function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I found this information in tensorflow's doc:

```
tf.layers.max_pooling1d?
Max Pooling layer for 1D inputs.

Arguments:
   inputs: The tensor over which to pool. Must have rank 3.
```

And:

```
tf.layers.max_pooling2d?

Max pooling layer for 2D inputs (e.g. images).

Arguments:
   inputs: The tensor over which to pool. Must have rank 4.
```

My confusion is why the inputs require rank 3 and rank 4, respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What might cause your confusion is the fact that one rank corresponds to the channels.

For 2D inputs (let's say images), the 4 ranks correspond to the following:

- `N` refers to the number of images in a batch.
- `H` refers to the number of pixels in the vertical (height) dimension.
- `W` refers to the number of pixels in the horizontal (width) dimension.
- `C` refers to the channels. For example, 1 for black and white or grayscale and 3 for RGB.

Depending on whether you want to have `channels_first` or `channels_last`, the ranks are ordered `NCHW` or `NHWC`, respectively.

For 1D-inputs there is only one of `H` or `W` (I prefer thinking about it as `W` but that's up to you) and so you have `NCW` (`channels_first`) or `NWC` (`channels_last`).

For more information about how the ordering (`channels_first` or `channels_last`) can affect the computation speed, you might want to take a look at the [TensorFlow Performance Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#data_formats) where I got the above information from.